# docker + vmworkstation: Ip not found al crear contenedor

Tags: docker, virtualización

Buen día comunidad de StackOverflow!

He instalado docker en Windows 7 x64 bits mediante el uso de chocolatey. La instalación la he configurado para utilizar docker con el driver de vmworkstation de forma que para crear un contenedor utilizo en la consola de comandos:

```
docker-machine --native-ssh --debug create -d vmwareworkstation default
```

El problema es que me está retornando ip not found for Mac... Como lo muestra la siguiente imagen:

[image: Error_docker_ip]

He estado leyendo y por ejemplo para el caso de virtual box normalmente se realiza un ipconfig y se prueba a colocar en el driver de conexión de red cada ip hasta que alguna de ellas coincide y es posible solucionar el problema, sin embargo, intenté esto mismo en vmware y no se solucionó.

Probé también cambiando tipo de conexión de red del VMware como por ejemplo NAT y bridged pero en ninguno de los dos casos se ha solucionado ya que sigue arrojando el error mostrado en la imagen anterior.

Mi pregunta es:

> Cómo soluciono este error? ya que no  es viable para mí cambiar de
>   driver (de VMware a Virtual box por ejemplo).

**Observación:** Debo acotar que no es problema de instalación o configuración en sí del VMware Workstation debido a que he creado numerosas maquinas virtuales desde el mismo y funcionan perfectamente.

Comment: prueba desactivar el firewall de windows durante el arranque de la vm (win7 descartaba varios tipos de ping en adaptadores internos)

Comment: Ok. Dejame intentar y te aviso. Gracias @aloMalbarez

Comment: @aloMalbarez intenté con su sugerencia pero persiste ip not found

Comment: probaste darle una ip fija en el config de dhcp? https://communities.vmware.com/thread/339217

Comment: @aloMalbarez He intentado colocar ip fija pero referenciandome a través de foros. Intento su alternativa y le aviso. Muchas gracias

Comment: @aloMalbarez Tampoco ha resultado. Muchas gracias por tu colaboración